# XSLT axis for siblings across trees?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am using XSLT to generate some webpages and I need to create links for the next and previous day. The structure is roughly as follows:

```
year
  month
    day
    day
    ...
  month
    day *
    day
    ...
  ...
...
```

Tried using the `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling` axis, but then discovered they of course won't work for the first and last day of a month. For example `preceding-sibling` would return nothing for the day marked with `*`.

How can I get the previous and next day for a given day, across the year and month "barriers", using XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The axis operators you are looking for in this case are **preceding** and **following**, which gets the preceding or following node regardless of the level in the hierarchy.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="following::day[1]" />

<xsl:copy-of select="preceding::day[1]" />
```

Comment: That did the trick! Is it possible to have the node name after `::` dynamic? Tried using `following::{$type}[1]`, but that gives me an Failed to compile the XPath expression..

Comment: Some xslt extension functions exist to do dynamic evaluation. However, in standard XSLT you could do `<xsl:copy-of select="following::*[local-name()=$type][1]" />`